# What does pimcore mean by inheritance

Tags: pimcore

I do not understand why pimcore would change the definition of class inheritance.

I want to create a class e.g. product with base information. From this, I want to create a new class e.g. Sneaker that inherits product - so that when i create a sneaker, it will have all properties of sneaker with inherited properties from product.

This doesnt work. It doesnt seem like this is what inheritance means in pimcore. I have read the pimcore documentation, but it doesnt explain clearly either. How would I go about the above need with pimcore 4 using the admin screens?

Thanks ~

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance works only for the objects of the same Object Class. Inheritance in PIM sense means that the data is inherited in nested objects. It doesn't work in the sense of OOP class inheritance.

In short: only one object class should cover all of your products. Use Object bricks, Key value pairs, Classification store, relations, etc. to model all the different product types.

Comment: Are you saying to create one object that satisfies all product category templates? Isnt that like creating a database that satisfies all product categories which is bad design? You would have many empty fields, etc.

Comment: Yes. For example: the area blocks are extra tables in database. You don't add the area block if you don't need those fields, thus no entry within that area block db table will be created.

Comment: In this case, would you agree it becomes impossible to limit permissions to product categories .. e.g. role a can manage sneakers, role b can manage shirts

Comment: No, it really doesn't. For example you can have sneakers in one folder and shirts in another one. You can then limit access to those folders on user or role level.

Comment: Great help. Thanks sir.

Comment: The idea is that I dont want the user to be able to add attributes. They would select e.g. "add sneaker", and those attributes would be listed. With the design you mention, it seems the user has to select which object bricks they want at the time of creating a "new product". This shouldnt be the case. How would you go about?

Comment: should i create  a class per product type (category)?

Comment: Creating a class per product type is one possibility and it could probably work for your needs. You could also check if user used an areablock that he wasn't supposed to be using within an object.preUpdate event and prevent creating it at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Class inheritances do not exist in pimcore. For example you have a sneaker and you want it to be added to the product category, this is not a piece of functionality that is supported by pimcore. You either place the sneaker product or if your scenario specifies creating the product category later, create a sneaker product with fake category. I am sure this behavior isn't very intuitive to people coming from more traditional OOP programming languages.

If you have any more misunderstandings, [take a look](https://factory.hr/services/pimcore-development).